# Aggregation at each document level mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a list of documents like this

```
[{
        "_id": "5dbc95f921d7625303fe2369",
        "name": "John",
        "itemsPurchased": [{
                "offer": "o1",
                "items": ["p1"]
            },{
                "offer": "o1",
                "items": ["p1"]
            },
            {
                "offer": "o1",
                "items": ["p2"]
            },
            {
                "offer": "o2",
                "items": ["p1"]
            }, {
                "offer": "o7",
                "items": ["p1"]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "zbc95f921d7625303fe2363",
        "name": "Doe",
        "itemsPurchased": [{
                "offer": "o1",
                "items": ["p11"]
            },{
                "offer": "o1",
                "items": ["p11"]
            },
            {
                "offer": "o2",
                "items": ["p13"]
            },
            {
                "offer": "o1",
                "items": ["p22"]
            },
            {
                "offer": "o2",
                "items": ["p11"]
            }, {
                "offer": "o3",
                "items": ["p11"]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And i am trying to compute unique offers on unique products by each customer, expecting the resultant to be like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5dbc95f921d7625303fe2369",
    "name": "John",
    "offersAndProducts": {
      "o1":2,
      "o2":2,
      "o3":1
},
{
  "_id": "zbc95f921d7625303fe2363",
    "name": "Doe",
    "offersAndProducts": {
      "o1":2,
      "o2":1,
      "o7":1
    }
]
```

I want to apply aggregations per document, After performing $unwind on itemsPurchased, applied $group on items and then on offer to eliminate the duplication:

```
{ 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "item" : {
                        "$arrayElemAt" : [
                            "$itemsPurchased.item", 
                            0.0
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "count" : {
                        "$sum" : 1.0
                    }, 
                    "offer" : "$itemsPurchased.offer"
                }
            }
        }
```

then,

```
{ 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$_id.offer", 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }
```

this gives the array of products and offers for all documents:

```
[
{o1:4,o2:3,o3:1,o7:1}
]
```

But i need it at document level.
tried `$addFeild`, but `$unwind` and $match operators gives invalid error.

Any other way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't understand the inputs and the desired output.   Focusing on just `John` for a moment, how do you get the output of `"o1":2,"o2":2,"o3":1` from the input?  What happened to `o7`?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti: Sorry for the typo.

Expected output was [
  {
    "_id": "zbc95f921d7625303fe2363",
    "name": "Doe",
    "offersAndProducts": {
      "o1": 2,
      "o2": 2,
      "o3": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "5dbc95f921d7625303fe2369",
    "name": "John",
    "offersAndProducts": {
      "o1": 2,
      "o2": 1,
      "o7": 1
    }
  }
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's an anti-pattern to `$unwind` an array and then to `$group` on the original `_id` since most operations can be done on the array directly, in a single stage.  Here is what such a stage would look like:

```
{$addFields:{
   offers:{$arrayToObject:{
      $map:{
         input:{$setUnion:"$itemsPurchased.offer"},
         as:"o",
         in:[
             "$$o", 
             {$size:{$setUnion:{$let:{
                vars:{items:{$filter:{
                    input:"$itemsPurchased",
                    cond:{$eq:["$$this.offer","$$o"]}
                }}},
                in:{$reduce:{
                    input:"$$items",
                    initialValue:[],
                    in:{$concatArrays:["$$value","$$items.items"]}
                }}
             }}}
          }]
      }
   }}
}}
```

What this does is create an array where each element is a two element array (which is a syntax that `$arrayToObject` can convert to an object where first element is key name and second is value) and the input is a unique set of offers and for each we accumulate an array of products, get rid of duplicates (with `$setUnion`) and then get the size of the result.  What this produces on your input is this:

```
"offers" : {
    "o1" : 2,
    "o2" : 2,
    "o3" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) twice. To count only unique `items` you can use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html). To build your keys dynamically you need to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$itemsPurchased"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$itemsPurchased.items"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: "$_id",
                offer: "$itemsPurchased.offer"
            },
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            items: { $addToSet: "$itemsPurchased.items" }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            offersAndProducts: { $push: { k: "$_id.offer", v: { $size: "$items" } } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            offersAndProducts: { $arrayToObject: "$offersAndProducts" }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h2-VkTebIBh)

Comment: Thank you very much for the query, one thing I noticed is that, the documents which have empty itemsPurchased are ignored, to make it work I initialized itemsPurchased with empty offer and an item 

{
    "_id": "zbc95f921d7625303fe2334",
    "name": "Doe",
    "itemsPurchased": [
      {
        "offer": "",
        "items": [
          ""
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

which returns :
{
    "_id": "zbc95f921d7625303fe2334",
    "name": "Doe",
    "offersAndProducts": {
      "": 1
    }
  } and ignore "" keys. is there any other way we can include these documents?

Comment: @user2033575 try this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#missing-field

Comment: I tried it :)  here is the snippet: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ofl4h-dzwlu, it was failing for empty array as it was not having an offer key but I tried padding the value with some random key 'q', It worked. Does MongoDB allow conditional push if the value is zero or keynot null?

Comment: $unwind and $group back on `_id` is an anti-pattern since you are recreating original documents, and that's quite inefficient.  See my solution for how this can be done by processing the array directly.

Comment: @user2033575 you can accept the other answer if you feel it's better since mine got downvoted